How to I convert NSAttributedString to AttributedString
I am using Xcode 16.1 and attempting to convert an NSAttributedString to an AttributedString but the compiler doesn't recognise the init:
Here's my code:
  let ns = NSAttributedString(string: "Fred")
  let s = AttributedString(ns)

The compiler gives the error: Cannot convert value of type 'NSAttributedString' to expected argument type 'NSCoder'. The correct initialiser doesn't appear in autocomplete.
It works OK in playground and a new project, so I'm guessing something must be wrong with my project. I've tried all the usual cleanup actions.

You need iOS 15.0+


Ensure you're using Swift 5.5 or newer, as AttributedString was introduced in Swift 5.5.
Extension Code
extension NSAttributedString {
    func toAttributedString() -> AttributedString? {
        return AttributedString(self)
    }
}

Usage
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let nsAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello, Xcode 16!", attributes: [
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
            .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
        ])

        if let attributedString = nsAttributedString.toAttributedString() {
            Text(attributedString)
        } else {
            Text("Failed to convert NSAttributedString")
        }
    }
}   


Thanks. I've tried this but it fails the same way - Cannot convert value of type 'NSAttributedString' to expected argument type 'NSCoder'
extension NSAttributedString {
func toAttributedString() -> AttributedString? {
return AttributedString(self)
}
}
I am using swift 6 and IOS 18.2 with Xcode 16.1

The error indicates that the compiler is interpreting the NSAttributedString initializer as expecting an NSCoder instead of the NSAttributedString conversion initializer. This often happens due to misalignment in your environment or the use of APIs incompatible with your current setup.

Thanks for your response. What do you mean by 'misalignment in your environment'? Also I have double checked that there are no incompatible APIs.
